# How would I package and deploy Python application like Mercurial hooks?

Tags: python, deployment, packaging

In this case, the application consists of one or more Python files, plus a `settings.ini` file. Now the Python files when being installed need to be installed in `~/.hg` (as default) or prompted where the user want them installed. The installation also requires text to be appended to files like `hgrc`.
Is there already a specific Python package that does all of this, or if anyone has any experience in this area please share.

As far as I have looked, Python packaging refers to `setuptools` and `easy_install`. 
The basis for packaging is a `setup.py` file. A problem with this is that such a setup file is used for a couple of dissimilar tasks:

- Generating documentation.
- Creating a release (source/binary).
- Actually installing the software.

Combining these tasks in one file is a bit of a hazard and leads to problems now and then.
or `distutils`, but I am not sure if these packages support the notion of user prompting and deployment like appending text to existing files, and creating new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would include a custom script (bin/ command) which will poke the users' .hgrc and others. Doing it without the user consent would be rude.

User story

- Install package: `easy_install pkgname` and this deploys `myproject-init-hg` (UNIX executable, can be also written in Python)
- The installation finished and tells the user to run commmand `myproject-init-hg`

setup.py include mechanism to distribute and deploy bin/ style scripts.

Comment: i wonder why no one thought of this, since this is a pretty basic issue, installing and deploying the python scripts that get developed. and of course i would prompt the user to input text which will be appended to the settings.ini, or ~/.hg/hgrc.

Comment: something like python setup.py install --foo, where  we can extend setup.py with --foo since we extend setup.py:
if "--foo" in sys.argv:
    do_foo_stuff()
woudl this work ?